# Calibre created EPUB: Why Pagina's EPUB Checker reports 2 types of errors concerning improper placement of "link" and "vlink" attributes in CSS?

Tags: html, css, validation, epub, calibre

How can I correct errors relating to improper placement of **link** and **vlink** attributes in EPUB’s CSS?

Calibre automatically generated the CSS for each of the linked sections of the EPUB file, i.e., xxx_split_xxx.htm. These related to the H1 and H2 elements for the table of contents.

The Pagina EPUB Checker shows two errors for each of the xxx_split_xxx.htm files relating to the headings and subheadings for the EPUB file’s headings and subheadings.

The results is 70 errors, i.e., two for each of the 35 HTM files.

Each error states that either the “link” or the “vlink” attribute is not allowed at its location in the CSS.

^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

"**Error while parsing the attribute "link" not allowed here**", …
"**Error while parsing the attribute "vlink"not allowed here**", …

(But, the links for the table of contents function properly)

---

Below is copy of a section of the CSS, wherein the offending line contains two errors, re: improper placement of 'link' and 'vlink' attributes.
Once again, this same section is repeated in each of the HTM files relating to the EPUB file’s headings and subheadings:

^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
At the beginning of 'body' section it reads, "**lang="EN-US" link="blue" vlink="purple" class="calibre**"

[This ERROR is incorrect placement of '**link**' and '**vlink**'attibutes that the EPUB complains about; these two errors are repeated in each HTM file.]

^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Above, the style in the last line appears in each of the 35 HTM files relating to the headings and subheadings of the table of contents.

There is a separate error for each of the “link” and “vlink” settings.

(The table of contents links work properly.)